# Home Directory Folders Problems

Tags: home

I have noticed over time that some of the folders in the Home folder have started having the icon disapear and at the bottom right of the files window when I leave the mouse over the missing folder it says "Link to symbolic Link". When I do ls -l it shows that they are now links and not directory's. I dident do this how did this happen and how do i make them directory's again and not links?[image]